# What framework for Objective C for iPhone supports resume on upload interrupt?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, http

I'm interesting in client side.
Some alternative to ASIHTTPRequest, cause it doesn't support.

Comment: I know this is for downloads, hence I've not posted it as an answer, but this was in last weeks iOS dev weekly: [Resuming Large Downloads](http://nachbaur.com/blog/resuming-large-downloads-with-nsurlconnection) does it provide any useful pointers for you?

Comment: It is only for downloads

Comment: Shame, from an HTTP standpoint the procedure is largely identical. :/

Comment: There are some strange people... I'm asking what I'm asking, because I don't know it and didn't find it in google...

Comment: So I'm strange for making a suggestion? WTF.  Having not had the requirement for resuming uploads I didn't know whether any content in that article could be applicable.. .hence the comment and not answer.  It's what they're for.

Comment: I'm not talking about you, I mean all these who had voted here

Comment: Ah, you've only received two down votes.  It's not that bad! :D  I don't think it will discourage people with helpful suggestions from making them.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this work from yesterday, and I only get the idea of get the offset at the http response header, use NSFileHandler to read file with large size, not more information I got, but I know google drive sdk support that, you can download it and have a look at it, however the code relation is complex as they call each other class so much